# Accessing BizTalk tracking data

Tags: elasticsearch, biztalk

I want to take all BizTalk tracking data and move it into Elasticsearch.

Is there a way to access the data before its put into the tracking database?

Or do I have to extract it from the database and then into Elasticsearch?

Can I use the BAM API for this?

Comment: You want to query all the tracking data with Elasticsearch? The SQL job TrackedMessages_Copy_BizTalkMsgBoxDb is responsible for copying tracked messages to the tracking database (BizTalkDTADB). It executes the bts_CopyTrackedMessagesToDTA stored procedure so you could take a look a that. But do keep in mind that custom changes to the BizTalk database are unsupported by Microsoft. BAM != tracking data by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change any BizTalk Stored Procedures.

How current do you need the data?

Here's two thoughts:

1. Take the Archives and load them into another database for Elasticsearch.
2. Do option 1 and point Elasticsearch to the DTA database as well.  Querying DTA separately is acceptable.  Just be sure to not block BizTalk's write operations.

Comment: Preferably right away but a few minutes delay is no problem. I will try option 2 and see how good the performance gets.